# Alternative to polling messages from Azure EventHub in SignalR application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure EventHub, which sporadically gets data from various devices. I would like to process the data and send them to client applications via SignalR. However, it seems the only possibility to get the data is having an infinite loop in the SignalR server application, which will periodically poll for data from the EventHub (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/musings_on_alm_and_software_development_processes/archive/2014/09/03/azure-event-hubs-queues-and-workers.aspx).

The only optimization, I have found, is to use Back off polling (http://www.developerfusion.com/article/120619/advanced-scenarios-with-windows-azure-queues/). Now I wonder - is there no better way to do the job? Both SignalR and EventHubs are there, to enable PUSH communication model. Are they not able to establish a bi-directional communication channel, which would allow them to send and receive messages based on events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that eventhub is the structure you need? Both Azure Queue and Azure Topics would provide you with an "OnEvent" signal in C# so that you can avoid polling. EventHub provides messages in a stream and is more intended for use with IoT signals in massive quantities and for Stream Analytics.

You can still, of course, forward messages to an eventhub after you've received a queue/topic message, if your architecture needs to visualize the stream of data, otherwise, I'd strongly consider [Azure Topics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/) or Azure Queue

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions/

Comment: Yes, I intend to connect thousands of devices, but they will not post data continuously. That is why I needed an IoT server, and EventHub seemed as the right choice. Another alternative is IoT Hub... Does IoT Hub provide OnEvent signal? If not, can I somehow forward messages between the EventHub and Topics/Queue (in both directions)? I would like to avoid adding unnecessary services (since everything comes at a price)...

Comment: The IoT Hub is basically device management with an EventHub built into it. No alternatives for you then, but as long as you're hosting your receiving end in Azure as well, then you're not incurring any extra changes by polling.

Comment: I understand this is an old post, but since Event Grid is available, I think that would be a good fit for this use case. I suppose even with Service Bus Topics there will be long polling